# Is there a way to pause a YouTube video in Google Chrome using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

What I'm trying is to type `tell application "Google Chrome" to pause` and make audio or video in Google Chrome pause. It wouldn't work, since it thinks pause is a variable.

Is there any way to either pause audio or video in all applications or just Google Chrome?

Comment: Typically pressing the **Play/Pause** _key_ on the keyboard should pause a **video** in **Google Chrome**. That said, **Stack Overflow** is not a _code writing service_ and it's expected that one provides enough relevant details to reproduce a coding issue you are having and or any research you've done to solve the issue on your own. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your post to include the relevant details.

Comment: @user3439894 my example is listed above as that is the only code I have. Is there a way to press the pause key using Applescript since `key code 100` which is F8 which is the pause key doesn't work for me in this case, even using `key down 63` which is function.

Comment: `pause` is not part of the **AppleScript** dictionary in **Google Chrome** and why it shows as a _variable_. So we are not wasting time, please add additional details to your question, as in the following: 1. A **URL** we can bring up in **Google Chrome** which has a video you'd like to _pause_.  2. What version of **macOS** are you running and on what _model_ of **Mac**? If a **Notebook**, are you also using an external keyboard and what type.

Comment: @user3439894 I want to pause a video on https://www.youtube.com. I'm using a MacBook Air without an external keyboard on MacOS Big Sur 11.4 Beta.

Comment: Have you searched the **Internet** for "AppleScript to pause YouTube video"?

Comment: The following _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ will play/pause a **YouTube** video in the _active tab_ of the _front window_ of **Google Chrome**: `tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button')[0].click();"`

Comment: @user3439894 this one works perfectly, since I only want to pause the video in the active tab. Is there any way to check if the video is paused so it doesn't unpause a video? Also could you write this comment as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will play/pause a **YouTube** video in the *active tab* of the *front window* of **Google Chrome**: `tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button')[0].click();"`

> @user3439894 this one works perfectly, since I only want to pause the video in the active tab. Is there any way to check if the video is paused so it doesn't unpause a video? Also could you write this comment as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer?

There may be an easier way using **JavaScript** to ascertain if the *active tab* of the *front window* in **Google Chrome** has a **YouTube** video playing, however, as I do not know the *code* for it, here is a way that works for me.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.7 and **macOS Big Sur** 11.2.3 using **Google Chrome** (Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (x86_64)) with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if not running of ¬
    application "Google Chrome" then return

tell application "Google Chrome"
    if (window count) = 0 then return
    set atx to the active tab index of its front window
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    --  # macOS Big Sur System Events bug issue.
    --  # If running macOS Big Sur, uncomment the next 
    --  # two lines if System Events reports an error.
    -- run
    -- delay 0.5
    tell application process "Chrome"
        if (the value of ¬
            attribute "AXTitle" of ¬
            radio button atx of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            the front window) ¬
            does not end with "Audio playing" then return
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    tell the active tab of its front window to ¬
        execute javascript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button')[0].click();"
```

---

**Notes:**

As coded, the `execute javascript` only happens if there is a **YouTube** video playing in the *active tab* of the *front window* of **Google Chrome**, thus pausing it. The *code*, as coded, cannot cause a paused video to play, regardless of the *active tab* or any *tab* of any *window*.

The `--  # macOS Big Sur System Events bug issue.` section in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is an attempted workaround to a **System Events** issue in **macOS Big Sur**, in that the exact same *code* without it runs without issue in **macOS Catalina** and may not work or needs adjusting. I am still trying to troubleshoot the issue in general. In my experience the issue has not been reproducible at will and as such alternate methods may have to be used if issue continues and cannot be diagnosed.

Use of other than exact versions tested under may be partially to blame for some errors, especially any that involve a change in the *hierarchical UI element structure* in any **UI Scripting** scenario using **System Events**.

- > Is there any way to either pause audio or video in all applications or just Google Chrome?

  - Typically pressing the Play/Pause *key* on the keyboard should pause a video in **Google Chrome**, and most other apps as well.
- > It wouldn't work, since it thinks pause is a variable.

  - `pause` is not part of the **AppleScript** dictionary in **Google Chrome** and why it shows as a *variable*.

In **Google Chrome**, running **AppleScript** *code* containing **JavaScript** needs the **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** menu item checked under: **View** > **Developer** -- Note that this used to be the default, however, at some time is was changed. For more information: https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=applescript

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: It isn't working and I tried it with the two lines, that you said could produce errors, uncommented and commented, I'm getting the same error which is 
`"System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of application process \"Chrome\". Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1 of application process "Chrome"`

Comment: @gurkensaas, RE: "I tried it with the two lines, that you said could produce errors, " --  That is not really what I said.  Anyway, I have tested the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ and it works for me as stated. BTW The error I originally got was `System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "Chrome". Invalid index.` and while I'm not entirely sure why in **macOS Big Sur** code that works without issue in **macOS Catalina** errors with **System Events** and I am still trying to troubleshoot the issue. I will do some more testing.

Comment: @gurkensaas, Obviously as coded if the _window_ didn't exist it wouldn't get that far in the _code_, assuming you are using all of the _code_ I posted as is.

Comment: I used the two lines you said I should uncomment if there were any errors so I did and it fixed nothing.

Comment: @gurkensaas, I added some additional information into the answer and since this works for me within what has been stated either in the answer or comments, all I can say is, sorry it doesn't work for you. I guess you will need another way to find out if the **YouTube** video is playing. I'll give it some thought, but you should do some research on your own too.

Answer (score 1):

This following AppleScript code will pause or play any instance of a YouTube video in any tab of any window in Google Chrome (whether visible or not).

```
pauseOrPlayYoutubeInChrome("ytp-play-button ytp-button", 0)

to pauseOrPlayYoutubeInChrome(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set youtubeTabsRef to a reference to (tabs of windows whose URL contains "youtube")
        repeat with youtubeTabs in youtubeTabsRef
            execute youtubeTabs javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & ¬
                theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();"
        end repeat
    end tell
end pauseOrPlayYoutubeInChrome
```

Comment: But is this practical? This is fine if one only has one tab with a YouTube video. Personally I almost always have multiple tabs with a YouTube video, with of course only one playing at a time. This is because I often open another tab from the play/what's next list, (or whatever it's called), so as to go be able to go back and select another from that list. This is because that list changes if one just clicks from it and one might loose the choice to another video in that list one wanted to watch too. So using this code would certainly not be useful in that use case scenario.

Comment: This works fine, but I think that @user3439894 answer is a little more compact and the extra functionality yours brings isn't really a gamechanger to me since I almost always have the running video on the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists of running 2 AppleScript in a specific environment.

It works for me using 1 window of Brave Browser(I think it is the same for google chrome) with 2 tabs on youtube.

First script force opening Brave browser, second run keystroke "K"

```
tell application "Brave Browser"
if it is not running then launch
activate
end tell


tell application "System Events"
keystroke "k"
end tell
```

[image: Example on Automator]

I have created a Quick Action on Automator and then I have followed this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/401262

And when trying to test it as a Keyboard Shortcut when using another Application, I was receiving an error like this "com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed to send keystrokes", so I realised that I need to give accessibility privileges(on Security and Privacy)  to all applications I want the script to work.

And After that, it works, but sometimes it gives the same error and it works again after some minutes(and never come back again) so I think this can help someone too.

This will pause or play the youtube video on the tab of the Brave Browser that is active.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think your solution is the nicest, since it pauses or plays and my question was: Is there a way to **pause** a youtube video in Google Chrome. I was aware of your solution, I just wanted to ask if there is any way to specifically pause a video. You're still receiving an upvote for the hassle though :)